# What words and/or phrases can you use in Japanese for story / storytelling / the art of telling a story?

Tags: word-choice, english-to-japanese

I'm doing a project and coming up with the words *rakugo*, *hanashi*, *sutōrīterā*, *kataribe*, *goribu* for the same expression but am not sure on the differences of each saying and what the best term to use is. Or if there are better terms.

Answer (score 2):

- 話（はなし hanashi）: This word of course primarily means "story", but it also refers to the action of talking or talking skills. 彼は話がうまい means "He is a good talker."
- 語り（かたり katari）： Refers to an action. This is closer to "storytelling" or "narrating", like of a documentary film. A more literary term than 話.
- 語り部（かたりべ kataribe）: A storyteller of old memories, ancient legends, fairy tales, etc. Typically an old person.
- ストーリーテラー: A loanword from English "storyteller". Everyone understands this word and it fits well with Western-style stage performances like a musical.
- 落語（らくご rakugo）： It's [*rakugo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rakugo), the name of a form of Japanese traditional stage performance. It doesn't mean storytelling in general.

The most generic and safe term for "story telling" is probably 語り, but the best word depends on what you're actually going to do.

I don't know what goribu means.

Comment: I guess that *goribu* is a misreading of 語り部.

Comment: @Earthliŋ 全く思いつきませんでしたｗ